# Cannot understand a C++ line

Tags: c++, function, arguments, character

I am reading a C++ code and came across a function:

```
double Nm_poissons_ratio(double /*Temp*/)

{

  double PR(0.0);

  PR = 0.31;

  return PR;

}
```

I don't understand what is the effect of /* */ characters which surround the Temp variable.

Thanks

Comment: @ Ami, Cory & ARL: Thank you for the answer. It is interesting that in the function argument we have variable type but no variable; wondering how does compiler interpret this type of argument.

Comment: There _is_ a variable. It just doesn't have a name you can use.

Answer (score 4):

If you write

```
double Nm_poissons_ratio(double Temp)
```

the compiler will warning. about an unused variable.

In this case, the coder wanted to retain the signature for some reason, but to avoid the warning. He/she therefore put a comment to show what it originally was.

---

Why is this the signature? It's hard to know.

- Perhaps this is an intermediate version of the code, and he/she plans to use this parameter in the future (this is actually an excellent case to retain the warning).
- Perhaps it's passed as a callback to some function that expects a specific signature.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. It is interesting that in the function argument we have variable type but no variable; wondering how does compiler interpret this type of argument.

Answer (score 2):

It means that the function takes a `double` argument, but they are commenting out the name (hence the `/* */`) because the argument to be named.

Likely because the compiler will warn them about an unused formal argument, since they do not use `Temp` anywhere in the function.

Answer (score 1):

All that is happening is the developer is commenting out a piece of code. Basically a comment tells the computer to ignore this piece of code. So, if you were developing a programming you would:

```
/* This is hidden to everyone BUT the programmer. */
```